# How can I allow a GIF to play in PowerPoint Normal mode?

Tags: gif, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a problem that the gif picture is not playing in normal mode, I know that this is normal, it would be playing only in presentation mode. I just want to check if there is any trick to make it work even in Normal mode.

Below screenshot shows the picture (gif) is not playing in normal mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the latest versions of PowerPoint place a [►] play button on the GIF that can be played in in the Normal View.